# how to add multiple url parameters in google apps script's doGet function

Tags: javascript, url, google-apps-script

I am making a web app using google app script but I encountered a problem
in doGet function

```
function doGet(e) {
  var invoice_id = e.parameter.invoice_id;
  var url = createDocument(invoice_id);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(url);
}
```

the problem is I have to pass multiple URL parameters but I can't.
please help me to pass multiple URL parameters and if you can say how to use POST method instead of Get method for the URL it will more secure.

Comment: For example, is this report useful for your situation? https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script#event-object-of-web-apps

Comment: If you want to pass multiple parameters why not use `UrlFetchApp`? Also, what exactly do you mean by using the `POST` method? You can make use of `doPost` - is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

The URL is just a string. The added parms have the format: key 'equal sign' value without any quotation marks (most of the time? - have never used any or seen any). One way to put pieces of string together is the 'plus sign' (+). The first parameter is separated from the URL by a 'question mark' (?). Additional parameters are separated by the 'and sign' (&).

```
let newUrl = myBaseUrl + '?' + 'parm1=abc' + '&' + 'parm2=123';
```